# How to get array through selected check boxes in jQuery or JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, cakephp

I want to get array of user selected check boxes, for example if user select the product1 and in product1 the email is a@acom like that, if user select many check boxes I want all email data in the array which he select against product. The data will get behalf of id, I am stuck at here, working to resolve that issue for 2 days but didn't get success:

```
      <?php v_start($this);?>
    <style>
    .highlight{ font-wieght:bold;   color:#F00;}
    .amounts{}
    .tick{ float:left; margin-top:-5px;}    
    .highlight .amount{ display : inline;}
    .tick img{  display:none;   width   : 25px; height  : 25px; margin-right: 10px; float   : left;}
    .highlight .tick img{   display : block;}
    </style>


    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function (){

        jQuery('.amounts').click(function (){
            var pname = jQuery(this).attr('product_name');
            if(!jQuery(this).hasClass('highlight')){
                jQuery('.amount-'+pname).removeClass('highlight');
                jQuery(this).addClass('highlight');
            }
            else {
                jQuery(this).removeClass('highlight');
                }           
        });

    });
    </script>
    <h1><?php echo __l('Step 1 ')?>-> <span style="color:red"><?php echo __l('Step 2')?></span></h1>

    <?php echo $this->FormManager->create('User',array_merge($form_options,array('default'=>true)));?>

        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" >
                    <?php    foreach($name as $product) { foreach ($product as $key) { 
         for($i=0;$i<sizeof($key['ProductPlan']);$i++) {
                        ?>
                    <th>
                        <?php echo $key['Product']['name']?>
                        <?php echo $this->FormManager->input($key['Product']['name'],array('type'=>'hidden','id'=>$key['Product']['name'],'class'=>'hid'))?> 
                    </th>
                    <?php  }}?>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <?php 
                        foreach($name as $product) {
                            $c = 0;
                    ?>

                        <?php 
                            foreach ($product as $key) {
                                $c++;
                        ?>
                            <td>
                          <?                                                                                                        for($i=0;$i<sizeof($key['ProductPlan']);$i++)    { ?>
                                <div 
                                     class   = 'packages'
                                     id      = "<?php echo $key['Product']['name'],$key['ProductPlan'][$i]['product_plan_id']?>" 
                                     onclick = "document.getElementById('<?php echo $key['Product']['name']?>').value='<?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['product_plan_id']?>';"
                                >

                                    <div product_name='<?php echo $key['Product']['slug']?>' class='amounts amount-<?php echo $key['Product']['slug']?>'>
                                        <div class='tick'>
                                            <?php echo $this->Html->image('tick.png', array('width'=>'25', 'height'=>'25'));?>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class='amount'>
                                            <?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['name'];?> 
                                            </br></br>
                                        </div>
                                        <div>Create Up To:<?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['limit'];?></div></br>
                                        <div>Product Plan Amount:<?php echo $key['ProductPlan'][$i]['product_plan_amount'];?>.$</div></br>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <?php }?>

                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>


                            </td>
                </tr>
<tr>        
</tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Comment: And your checkboxes are where...?

Comment: @axel.michel checkboxes are calling through input

Comment: Only input I can see in your code is type hidden

Comment: You are reposting your code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908447/how-i-can-calucate-the-grand-total-amount-when-user-select-the-total-plan, if you are not satisfied with the answers you get, you should think about what and how you ask. Look at the answers below, nobody is sure what you want . And as far as I can see you don't even have checkboxes. Work on your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you're asking, would this solution help?

http://jsfiddle.net/rG6bF/1/

```
$(":checkbox").click(function(e) {
    $.each($(":checked"),function(idx,chkbox) {
        log($(chkbox).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It would make it easier to help you if you could provide the HTML-output instead of the PHP-source.

If you want to target all checked checkboxes, and perhaps their relative email input fields, you could use something like this:

```
var email_arr = new Array();
$('input:checkbox:checked').each(function() { //goes through each checked input box
    email_arr.push($(this).siblings("input.email").val()); //Gets the value of an email input field
});
```

The important thing is how you place the email input-field. If it's not in the same element as the checkbox, you might need to traverse up a node or two using .parent or .parents.

Hope that helps,

//Somersault